# MicrosoftOfficeEditDocument didn't work in Chrome

Tags: ajax, webdav, ithit-ajax-file-browser

I'm evaluating the IT Hit WebDAV AJAX Library. When my script calling MicrosoftOfficeEditDocument(url), it works in IE but not in Google Chrome (it just didn't do anything when called in Chrome). What am I missing?

Here is how I called it:

```
ITHit.WebDAV.Client.DocManager.MicrosoftOfficeEditDocument("http://server.com/file.docx");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until today the IT Hit WebDAV AJAX Library was using the protocol extension installed by Microsoft Office 2013 to open the document in Google Chrome. However Google Chrome have blocked that protocol for some reason.

Today we have published an update that fixes this issue. Now in case of Google Chrome the IT Hit WebDAV AJAX Library is using browser plug-in installed by Microsoft Office 2013 and 2010.