# EditDocument doesn't always work in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, webdav, ithit-ajax-file-browser

I am having a similar problem to [MicrosoftOfficeEditDocument didn't work in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24170688/microsoftofficeeditdocument-didnt-work-in-chrome).

I did download the updated library as said in the answer and it works fine with Office 2013 but not with 2010.
With Office 2010, I have some files that open and some that don't, they are not always the same ones. I tried with .doc, .docx, .ppt, .pptx, .xls and .xlsx.

I call the edit document fonction with :
`ITHit.WebDAV.Client.DocManager.EditDocument(sDocumentUrl, javaAppletFilePath);`

EDIT :

It actually seems to be a problem of length of file url. When my file url (sDocumentUrl) is longer than the length of my script url in which I call EditDocument it works perfectly fine. But when it is shorter, the end of the script url is added after sDocumentUrl which makes the call fail. And this only happens with Chrome and Office 2010.

Any way to make this work ?

Comment: Does this occur consistently for you? It works sometimes for me, but other times it doesn't work. Sometimes if I change one character in the string file URL it works.

Comment: No it isn't consistent. When I posted the question it didn't work often and one file could be open at a time and after couldn't.
Right now it seems to work almost all the time except for .pptx which doesn't always open.

Comment: It seems to work fine if I first open the file in IE and then in Chrome.

Comment: What do you mean by, "the end of the script url is added after sDocumentUrl"?

Comment: If I call my script : "http://ipaddress:port/myscript.php" and my document Url is "http://ipaddress/shorter.doc" ItHit tries to open "http://ipaddress/shorter.docpt.php"

Comment: Wow that's weird. Does that still happen when you add `'\0'` to the end of the document URL?

Comment: With '\0' and MicrosoftOfficeEditDocument it works fine !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Add `'\0'` to the end of the URL**

Add a `'\0'` (null) to the end of the string you are passing to `MicrosoftOfficeEditDocument()`. Like `MicrosoftOfficeEditDocument(path + '\0');`. Also, you should use `MicrosoftOfficeEditDocument()` instead of `EditDocument()` because `EditDocument()` will try to call `JavaEditDocument()` because of the null terminated string.

This is a solution taken from here - https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=269183#c5

For more info - [opening webdav files in Chrome via the Office Authorization plug-in for NPAPI browsers fails for certain files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18218533/opening-webdav-files-in-chrome-via-the-office-authorization-plug-in-for-npapi-br)

**Check for ActiveX first**

However, you should not add the `'\0'` to the path when `MicrosoftOfficeEditDocument()` will open the document via the SharePoint.OpenDocument ActiveX object or else the ActiveX plugin will not recognize the file format via extension and try to open the document via `undefined:ofe|u|` instead of `ms-word:ofe|u|` for example. To do this you should check for ActiveX before appending the `'\0'`.

```
if (!('ActiveXObject' in window)) {
    path = path + '\0';
}

ITHit.WebDAV.Client.DocManager.MicrosoftOfficeEditDocument(path)
```

**Warning**: this solution breaks `MicrosoftOfficeEditDocument` in Firefox. Firefox does not like the `\0` terminated string.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't test this because I'm also using sabredav and it breaks everything when I add a '\0' into the URL of the document. But thanks for the solution anyway.

Comment: But does adding `'\0'` to the path when calling `DocManager.MicrosoftOfficeEditDocument(path + '\0');` make the document open consistently (even if your WebDAV implementation fails because of it)?

Comment: This solution has been working for me. Hopefully you would just have to modify your WebDAV server to handle the null terminated string.

Comment: Yes it works fine with MicrosoftOfficeEditDocument but I think I have found the actual problem, it isn't random as I first thought (see my edit)